# Highcharts sankey diagram, series color

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

How to make the series color identical to the data color?

In the example, the "imbalance" data is red, but the series is colored blue.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },

    series: [{
            colors: ["#90CAF9", "#F44336", "#1565C0"],
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            {name: "prop-1", color: "#90CAF9", from: "prop-1", to: "transition", weight: 0},
            {name: "prop-2", color: "#90CAF9", from: "prop-2", to: "transition", weight: 4.14},             
            {name: "imbalance", color: "#F44336", from: "imbalance", to: "transition", weight: 0.6},
            {name: "prop-3", color: "#1565C0", from: "transition", to: "prop-3", weight: 4.74},
            {name: "prop-4", color: "#1565C0", from: "transition", to: "prop-4", weight: 0},
        ],
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]

});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s3xnm5v8/

[image]

**Update**
Understood. It is necessary to use Nodes.
https://jsfiddle.net/p4f21w7e/

Answer (score 7):

The key thing to realise is that there are two ways to colour your chart:

- The series colours (series[].colors) will colour the nodes.
- The series data (series[].data[].color) colour your flows.

Take a look at this example:

```
 series: [{
    colors: ["#880000",  "#AFAFAF",  "#008800", "#000088", "#ffb238", "#ffee37"],
    data: [

        {color: "#BB0000", from: "Red", to: "Colour Demo", weight: 10},
        {color: "#00BB00", from: "Green", to: "Colour Demo", weight: 4},                       {color: "#0000BB",  from: "Blue", to: "Colour Demo", weight: 6},
        {color: "#ffb238", from: "Colour Demo", to: "Orange", weight: 10},
        {color: "#ffee37",  from: "Colour Demo", to: "Yellow", weight: 10}
    ]
}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjjjssssfidd/c2dbjshx/2/

The nodes are coloured using the series colours in the order in which they are rendered (left to right, moving down). So, in this example:

- "Red" first (using series[].colors[0])
- Then "Colour Demo" (which uses series[].colors[1])
- Back to Green (series[].colors[2])
- Down to "Blue" (using series[].colors[3])
- Then over to Orange (series[].colors[4])
- Finally Yellow (series[].colors[5])

The flow itself is coloured as per the associated color for that data point, so this is a straight forward association.

Comment: But is there a way to specifically set "Red" node to "#88000" rather than trying to get everythink in the right order to match the colors specified in series[].colors ?

Comment: I think I got my answer from this : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/sankey/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'colors' property of the sankey series type.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.colors

```
series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: [
        {from:'Brazil', to:'Portugal', weight:5},
        ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Canada', 'France', 5 ],
        ['Canada', 'England', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'France', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5 ],
        ['Mexico', 'England', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'France', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'Spain', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'England', 5 ]
    ],
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series',
    colors: ['#00796B', '#ff0000', '#00ff00','#0000ff']
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Fine! Thank you =)

Comment: But it still works weird. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/k62jpc1x/. Why is the imbalance graph not red?

Comment: You need to remove the 'color' property from your data objects. then you can re-order the colours to get the right result https://jsfiddle.net/u08zg2nf/

Comment: Also the 'colorIndex' on your 'nodes' can be used to reference colours directly from the colors array I originally mentioned.